# Get the size of all the documents in a query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, bson, mongo-shell, mongodump

Is there a way to get the size of all the documents that meets a certain query in the MongoDB shell?

I'm creating a tool that will use `mongodump` (see [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongodump/)) with the `query` option to dump specific data on an external media device. However, I would like to see if all the documents will fit in the external media device before starting the dump. That's why I would like to get the size of all the documents that meet the query.

I am aware of the `Object.bsonsize` method described [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongo-shell/#miscellaneous), but it seems that it only returns the size of one document.

Comment: Mongo has to scan all documents to get the size. So I see only incremental approach when you iterate through your query result.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's the answer that I've found:

```
var cursor = db.collection.find(...); //Add your query here.
var size = 0;
cursor.forEach(
    function(doc){
        size += Object.bsonsize(doc)
    }
);
print(size);
```

Should output the size in bytes of the documents pretty accurately.

I've ran the command twice. The first time, there were 141 215 documents which, once dumped, had a total of about 108 mb. The difference between the output of the command and the size on disk was of 787 bytes.

The second time I ran the command, there were 35 914 179 documents which, once dumped, had a total of about 57.8 gb. This time, I had the exact same size between the command and the real size on disk.

Comment: works flawlessly! is it okay to use it in production?

Answer (score 3):

Starting in `Mongo 4.4`, [`$bsonSize`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/bsonSize/#exp._S_bsonSize) returns the size in bytes of a given document when encoded as BSON.

Thus, in order to sum the bson size of all documents matching your query:

```
// { d: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] }
// { a: 1, b: "hello" }
// { c: 1000, a: "world" }
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $group: {
    _id: null,
    size: { $sum: { $bsonSize: "$$ROOT" } }
  }}
])
// { "_id" : null, "size" : 177 }
```

This `$group`s all matching items together and `$sum`s grouped documents' `$bsonSize`.

[`$$ROOT`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.ROOT) represents the current document from which we get the bsonsize.